# What's wrong with my for-loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to print each digit of an integer and then sum of each digit like this. There is something wrong with the loops but I cant seem to figure it out. I want it to be like this:

```
Please enter a number: 194
1 * 100 = 100
9 * 10 = 90
4 * 1 = 4
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrintEachDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number: ");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        String s = ""+num;
        double d = 0; 
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) { 
            for(int j = s.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) { 
                d = Math.pow(10,j); 
                System.out.println(s.charAt(i) + " * " + d
                                   + " = " + (s.charAt(i)*d)); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output of my code:

```
Enter the number: 194
1 * 100.0 = 4900.0
1 * 10.0 = 490.0
1 * 1.0 = 49.0
9 * 100.0 = 5700.0
9 * 10.0 = 570.0
9 * 1.0 = 57.0
4 * 100.0 = 5200.0
4 * 10.0 = 520.0
4 * 1.0 = 52.0
```

Comment: Work on your code conventions... it makes your code easier to read. If no one can read your code, no one can help you as quick.

Comment: If you're trying to *sum* each digit, why are you multiplying and using `Math.pow`? If you want to sum the digits, then convert each ASCII character to a number and add them up.

Comment: You do not need the second for loop! Add a second iteration var instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a couple problems with your code.

The first problem is that you don't need two loops, you just need one.

The second problem is confusing `char`s and `int`s. `'0'` is not the same as `0`; instead, `'0'` is a numeric value representing the encoding of that character (which turns out to be 48). So to get the correct value that you want, you should subtract `'0'` from the `char` before doing your math.

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) { 
    d = Math.pow(10, s.length() - i - 1); 
    int value = s.charAt(i) - '0';
    System.out.println(value + " * " + d
                       + " = " + (value*d)); 
}
```

This will get it close to the output you wanted. It's still showing the `.0` at the end though, because `d` is a `double`. Make it an `int` to fix that.

```
//This can be scoped to inside the loop, so you don't need to declare it beforehand
int d = (int)Math.pow(10,j);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrintEachDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number: ");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        String s = "" + num;
        int len = s.length() - 1;
        long d = 0;
        if (len < 2) {
            d = 1;//For single digit
        } else {
            d = (long)Math.pow(10, len);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(s.charAt(i) + " * " + d + " = "
                    + ((s.charAt(i) - '0') * d));
            d = d / 10;
        }
    }
}
```